# Load local asset into the browser (not into a WebView)

Tags: android, uri, android-contentprovider, assets

My problem is that I need to load an HTML file that is in my project into the Browser.

For the particulars of the application, I can't:

- Copy the asset in the SDcard, because it could be unmounted when the file needs to be read.
- Use a `WebView` in the application. It needs to be the browser.

My approach so far is has been trying to use a `ContentProvider`. I have been following this [tutorial](http://helpmeco.de/2012/2/serving-android-webview-resources-with-content-providers). In this approach, my main problem is how to pass to the Browser the `Uri` and get the call to my `ContentProvider`.

I have tried to send an Intent to the Browser like this:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse( "content://myprovider_authority/my_file.html" ):
intent.setData(uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

but the stock Android Browser doesn't understand the URI and tries to search the URI in Google.

Does anyone know how should I pass this `Uri` to the Browser so I receive a request in my `ContentProvider`?

---

**SOLUTION EXPLAINED:**

@gimix solution worked for me even though the approach is without using a `ContentProvider`. I  explain it bit more.

What he proposes is to send a data `URI` scheme to the browser. This means encoding our local `HTML` asset file to `Base64` and pass it using an `Intent`. The Browser will interpret that data and render the result. Some code will help to understand it:

```
String html = "";
try {
    InputStream is = mContext.getAssets().open( "my_file.html" );
    int size = is.available();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
    is.read(buffer);
    is.close();
    html = new String(buffer);
} 
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

intent.setData( Uri.parse( "data:text/html;charset=utf-8;base64," + Base64.encodeToString( html.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP )));
startActivity(intent);
```

The tricky thing here are images inside the `HTML`. For those you have two options, encode those images and place the actual encoding inside the `HTML` encoding or refer to Web images (so you don't need to do any other encoding).

My `HTML` is quite simple and I used Web images, so this totally worked for me.

(Not sure if all browsers support data schemes though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android browser supports the [data URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)

Following the Wikipedia example, you could use the following URL to show an HTML page with the text "42":

```
data:text/html;charset=utf-8,%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%3Chtml%20lang%3D%22en%22%3E%3Chead%3E%3Ctitle%3EEmbedded%20Window%3C%2Ftitle%3E%3C%2Fhead%3E%3Cbody%3E%3Ch1%3E42%3C%2Fh1%3E%3C%2Fbody%3E%3C%2Fhtml%3E
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot have the default Browser work directly with your `ContentProvider`. The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Browser.html) doesn't public any methods for what you want.

Answer (score 0):

There is even another solution that might work depending on the case. Implement a local HTTP server that serves the project assets to the browser.

For this you will need to be sure your local server is running when the browser requests the file. This should not be a problem if your app is the one sending the intent to the browser.

Also choose a port dynamically to avoid opening one that is already in use.

I tried with this open source project [NanoHTTPD](http://elonen.iki.fi/code/nanohttpd/) for the HTTP server. It didn't take me long to make it work like a charm.